# Are socket.io messages encrypted on https express (node.js) applications?

Tags: node.js, express, encryption, https, socket.io

I am building an Express (Node.js) application which uses socket.io, by one side, and an authentication system by the other.

My question points to the fact that I need to pass sensitive information to identify socket requests, and I know that either by post data (which goes encrypted), or by https headers (which go encrypted too), it is secure to do this, but I do not know if the messages sent by socket.io through https are also encrypted.

This is in order to avoid man in the middle attacks in socket.io communications.

I have read that Facebook uses a way to encrypt, and Telegram another one. But maybe it is not needed, I thought, I have not checked anything of this with Wireshark, so maybe someone knows a bit more about how to deal with this, keeping things as simple as possible, but secure.

Comment: I'm uncertain of exactly what you're doing (you give no code) but anything sent over https is encrypted.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I added how I did it finally.

Answer (score 0):

The way it finally worked for me to stablish socket.io connection through https and with authorization header as session token:

```js
const socketio = require("socket.io-client");

const client = socketio("/namespace", {
    transports: ["websocket"],
    secure: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    extraHeaders: {
        authorization: "Bearer: " + MY_SESSION_TOKEN
    }
});

client.connect();
client.on("message", function(data) {
    console.log("Received: " + message);
    client.disconnect();
});
```